# Getting "<HTML>" instead of query result using php to access database from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm) to implement a simple user log in activity. I am new to php and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. In the tutorial where he gets the "Role" attribute for his query I get a string < HTML> I am trying to see that if my code is getting any results.
Here is my LoginActivity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



   BufferedReader in;
    private int byGetOrPost = 0;
    int success = 0;
    String id1 = "";
    String password1 = "";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        Defining onClickListener for Login Button
        Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Check credentials
                EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_txt);
                EditText pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_txt);
                id1 = phone.getText().toString();
                password1 = pwd.getText().toString();
                new SigninActivity().execute(id1, password1);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            if(byGetOrPost == 0){ //means by Get Method

                try{
                    String id = (String)arg0[0];
                    String password = (String)arg0[1];
                    String link = "#######/android_connect/check_user_login.php?id="+id+"&password="+password;

                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                    request.setURI(new URI(link));
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                }

                catch(Exception e){
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            TextView reg=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_txt);
            reg.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Php file check_user_login.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("###.###.###.##:####","####","######","heycab");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$id= $_POST['id'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Role FROM tb_login where 
id=$id and Password='$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

But at the end, regardless of what credentials i enter, "reg" textview is always showing this text. "< HTML>"

Comment: Do you get exception in activity? And you tried to Log result?

Comment: If my code returns with an exception it should show "Exception: ..." in my "reg" textview. And my app doesn't crash or forced stop if that's what you mean. It just shows the string "HTML" with angle brackets around it.

Comment: leave android out of it. Debug your php script using the browser. Look at the webserver log or enable errors to see what went wrong in your php scripts

Comment: again I am quite new to php and I actually don't know how I could run it without calling it from the java code. Do I like open the php file in a browser directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't see the error when I opened the php on my browser because the server upon which the file was placed had its `error_display` settings set to `false`. So instead I used [Xamp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). Placed the file inside the directory, 'xamp/htdocs/' and then after turning on the Apache and MySQL from Xamp Control Panel, I entered the file url, "localhost/htdocs/file_name.php" in the browser. Now it showed me the error that I couldn't see before. So if anyone else gets the has the same problem they can use this method to identify the errors in their php files. Oh and I had the user and password for my database wrong. In case anyone was wondering.